# Why is my Female Red Ear Slider laying eggs, and how do I stop it?

Tags: turtles, eggs

We’ve had our Female Red Ear Slider for about 10 years. She’s in a tank that holds 90 gallons currently. Originally, we had little pellet rocks at the bottom of the tank about 2 inches deep. She started pushing her backside into the rocks acting like she was going to lay an egg, but never did. About a year ago, we removed the pellet rocks thinking it will help. Ever since then she’s been laying eggs non stop. Within this past year she’s laid about 17-20 unfertilized eggs. Today she laid 9 eggs in a row. Is there a way to stop this from happening? Is there something we are doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you could not stop it. You could be happy that your turtle not died because she was eggbound!

Long answer you will find in this pets.SE question: [Red eared slider laying eggs into the water](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/18912/red-eared-slider-laying-eggs-into-the-water)

Comment: My first thought was "put a cork in it", but your answer is much better :)

Comment: ^^ With cork at the hind end the turtle will have a much worse balance in the water ...

Comment: Not if the density of the cork is uniform and mostly equal to the density of the turtle :D

Comment: cork is well known for floating. If you can bind a piece of cork to the tank's wall, it can suit as basking area and holds the turtle's weight :)

Comment: I used the "object" meaning of the word, not the "wooden material". I think some people call it a stopper. Please see the "(Redirected from Cork (plug))" part https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stopper_(plug)

Comment: In German also the stopper and the natural material have the same word :)